# Docker mounts on demand containers in the Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins

Can you please help what is wrong in that

```
"type:bind,source:/var/run/docker.sock,destination:var/run/docker.sock,key=0"
```

Below is the error:

```bash
Note: Disabled 52 sec ago due to error. Will re-enable in 4 min 7 sec.
Reason: Template provisioning failed.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:  
  Invalid mount: expected key=value comma separated pairs, or 'readonly' keyword
at com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.DockerTemplateBase.parseMountsString(DockerTemplateBase.java:893)
at com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.DockerTemplateBase.parseMountsStrings(DockerTemplateBase.java:880
at com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.DockerTemplateBase.fillContainerConfig(DockerTemplateBase.java:809)
at com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.DockerTemplate.fillContainerConfig(DockerTemplate.java:272)
at com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.DockerTemplate.doProvisionNode(DockerTemplate.java:715)
at com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.DockerTemplate.provisionNode(DockerTemplate.java:677)
at com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.DockerCloud$1.run(DockerCloud.java:376)
at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

How can I fix the parameter and avoid the `Invalid mount IllegalArgumentException`?

Comment: What is unclear with `expected key=value comma separated pairs`?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The [docker plugin source code](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker-plugin/blob/0eb98f1a4bc0d9464c71bde58e696b5749f086eb/src/main/java/com/nirima/jenkins/plugins/docker/DockerTemplateBase.java#L884-L894=) shows

```java
    private static void parseMountsString(String mnt, List<Mount> mountListResult) {
        Mount mount = new Mount().withType(MountType.VOLUME);
        BindOptions bindOptions = null;
        TmpfsOptions tmpfsOptions = null;

        final String[] tokens = mnt.split(",");
        for (String token : tokens) {
            final String[] parts = token.split("=");
            if (!(parts.length == 2 || parts.length == 1 && "readonly".equals(parts[0]))) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid mount: expected key=value comma separated pairs, or 'readonly' keyword");
            }
```

In your case, after splitting by '`,`', the `type:bind` part would trigger the error.
Because adter splitting `type:bind` by '`=`', there would be only one "part".
`type=bind` should work better.
Same with `destination:var/run/docker.sock` => `destination=var/run/docker.sock`